# Compare if Strings have the Same number of digits

Tags: java

I´m trying to compare 2 different strings. but I'm not looking if they have they are exactly the same, I´m looking if they contain the same number of digits.

Example:
iF my the `String b = 1234567891234567` and i entered on `String a = abcdefghijklmnop`, i want to know if they have the same number of digits,

```
import java.util.*;

class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a;
        String b = new String("1234567891234567");

        System.out.println("Enter your number");
        a = lector.nextLine();

        if(a.length() == b.lenght()){
            System.out.println("They have the same number of digits");

        }else{
            System.out.println("They dont have the same number of digits");
        }
    }
}
```

I know that i cant use the `==` because they are for integers. If I use the equals statement, the program will compare if the string entered is exactly as the other string.

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please supply working code firstly, I want to know that if I spend time helping you with this I'm not also having to help you get over syntax errors.

Comment: By "digits" do you mean "characters"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have to check the lengths of the string then simply use

```
a.length() == b.length()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the digits with:

```
str.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

then compare the length of the Strings.

For your example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a;
    String b = new String("1234567891234567");

    System.out.println("Enter your number");
    a = lector.nextLine();

    if(a.replaceAll("\\D+","").length() == b.replaceAll("\\D+","").length()){
        System.out.println("They have the same number of digits");

    }else{
        System.out.println("They dont have the same number of digits");
    }
}
```

Comment: When it asks me: Enter you number and i entered: abcdefghijkmnlop after doing this the message: They dont have the same number of digits is displayed. And if you count both values 1234567891234567 vs abcdefghijkmnlop they have the same amount of digits

Comment: The confusion here lies in the use of the word "digits" instead of "characters".  Nick's answer here does indeed check whether the number of digits are the same, but not the number of characters, which is what you want. "Digits" are numerals, 1 through 0.  "Characters" are any symbol that's part of a string -- letters, numeric digits, punctuation, and so forth.